# Create django object using a view with no form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I was wondering how I would be able to create an object in a database based the URL a user is going to.

Say for example they would go to /schedule/addbid/1/ and this would create an object in the table containing the owner of the bid, the schedule they bidded on and if the bid has been completed. This here is what I have for my model so far for bids.

```
class Bids(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField("ID", primary_key=True, editable=False,)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
   biddedschedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule)
   complete = models.BooleanField("Completed?", default=False)
```

The biddedschedule would be based on the number in the URL as the 1 in this case would be the first schedule in the schedule table

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get the `id` parameter using `urls.py`:

```
#urls.py
from appname.views import some_view

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^schedule/addbid/(?P<id>\d+)$', some_view),
    ...
)
```

Take a look at the documentation about [capturing parameters in the urlconf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/).

And then, in `views.py` you should construct a `Bids` Object using the `id` passed in the URL, the currently logged in user (`request.user`), and the `biddschedule` from your DB. For example:

```
#views.py
def some_view(request, id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # get the biddschedule from your DB
        # ...
        bids = models.Bids(id=id, owner=request.user, biddedschedule=biddedschedule)
        bids.save()
        return HttpResponse("OK")
    return Http404()
```

Answer (score 2):

Catch the number via the urlconf. Get the current user via `request.user`. Create a model instance by calling its constructor, and save it to the database via its `save()` method.

Answer (score -1):

```
`#view.py under a post or get method`

    new_bird, created = Bids.objects.get_or_create(
         owner = user_obj,
          biddedschedule = biddedschedule_obj,                
          complete = bool
          )
    new_bird.save()
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.